# 403 error everytime I login to my site, but csrftoken is in my form. DJANGO

Tags: django

I am experiencing 403 error when I uploaded my site on pythonanywhere.com, but it works fine in localhost. It keeps on saying 403 forbidden when I try to login an account, even I input a wrong password. I tried to look at the `request cookies` in my browser, it does not detect the `csrftoken`, but when I check the checkbox that shows `filtered out request cookies`, I can see the `csrftoken` and its value and other things.

I have `{% csrf_token %}` in my `login` form and I am using the default login view of django.

here's my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["jeremiramos.pythonanywhere.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',

    #installed apps
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
    'main',
    'cms',
    'ckeditor',
    'students',


]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cvsproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates' ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'cms.context_processors.add_data_to_base_template',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cvsproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/jeremiramos/cvs/staticfiles"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'

# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
#     # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
#     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
#         'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
#     ]
# }
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://jeremiramos.pythonanywhere.com",
]

# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
# SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

here's my login form:

```
{% block content %}
<div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80); height: 83.8vh;">
    <header class="masthead" style="color: white;">
  <div class="container d-fixed h-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="mx-auto text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 align-self-center" style='margin-top:7rem'>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class='form-group'>
                        <legend class= 'border-bottom mb-4'>CVS Portal</legend>
                        {{form|crispy}}

                    </fieldset>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type='submit'>Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <small><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></small>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `"http://jeremiramos.pythonanywhere.com"` → are you sure that pythonenywhere using http protocol without ssl?

Comment: What messages do you see in your web app's error log on PythonAnywhere? (Most recent logs are at the bottom.)

Comment: @rzlvmp sir, so you mean i need to make it https?

Comment: @caseneuve i only see 403 forbidden error. ```2022-05-04 10:23:41,482: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /login/```

Comment: It appears to be working for me. Do you have a browser extension that may be blocking the cookies?